# Integration User and Oauth Connected Apps

Tags: integration, connected-apps

Just want to get clarification on something we're noticing in our org. Its regarding a new integration user we've created for an external application to connect to Salesforce. We also created a Connected App for this application to authenticate using OAuth. All of this is setup and working up to this point.

But one thing that we don't understand is there is a related list on the integration user detail page named "OAuth Connected Apps". We're concerned because although we are connecting fine and data is getting return to the external application no records are showing up in this "OAuth Connected Apps" related list. Should we expect to see Authorization or Access tokens in this list?

We just want to make sure we aren't bypassing the connected app in anyway, which we assume not, but just want to run it by the community and see. All comments are appreciated. Thanks ahead of time for the support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a recently introduced SF bug. The connected app used to show up on User regardless of the authorization policy if the access token was issued. Now it doesn't show up in some cases, notably in JWT flow if the oAuth policy on the connected app is set to `Admin approved users are pre-authorized`.

You can view the tokens issued by the app by clicking on `View OAuth Usage` link in the `OAuth Policies` sections on the connected app. Another option is to take a look at Login History via the admin console. Filtering history for `Login Type` set to `Remote Access 2.0` will show you all oAuth 2.0 authorizations and `Application` column will show you what connected app was used.

Comment: This looks to be a bug, we verified they are using the oauth settings in the connected app. Thank you for the reply, much appreciated.